# RSS feed for library is blank

Tags: document-library, xml, rss

We're on SharePoint 2010 and trying to get the RSS feed of a library. The "Allow RSS for this list" is set to Yes. On the library, we go to Library > RSS Feed and we see "Site Name: Library Name" but the page is blank -- the "Displaying" text on the right says "0/0". Why aren't we seeing the XML for the feed?

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the configuration in the Item Limit area of the RSS Settings for the document library?  If you create a view with a similar filter, do any documents appear?  If nothing was changed in the days setting, there would be no XML as there would be no matching items.

Edit or upload a document, then check the RSS link again.

Comment: Thanks, @PirateEric, for your response. I added a new document and now it shows all the items. I'm trying to use the RSS feed with the JWPlayer to do a video playlist of videos in a video library. What's your recommendation on doing this?

Comment: I've never heard/of used JWPlayer so I don't know what it needs to function.  If it needs XML, the other methods to get the data would be through the client object model or using jQuery and SPServices or doing the VS development route..

Comment: Thanks. A follow-up: How can you get the RSS feed to always show the same list? In other words, I had to add a document to the library for the feed to show items. Is there a way that it will show all items in the library permanently? Thanks.

Comment: Adjust the RSS Settings so that the days are far reaching and the items are far reaching, like 5000 days and 5000 items.